# translate php key to javascript for logging

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a php loop that is properly displaying the values i expect as html headings.

What I want to do here is create a hidden input for each one, so if there are 15  tags for categories, I want 15  hidden inputs.

The code below 'works' by logging the correct info however, it only ever logs the first one.

Obviously, this is becaue the php/html loop has a key assigned but the javascript is pulling a non-unique ID.

How can I properly translate this key into javascript so I can log the actual value of the selected item, rather than just the first?

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)

<h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="edit_category" id="edit_category" value="{{$item->category}}" />

@endforeach



function editCommentModal(){

console.log(document.getElementById("edit_category").value);

}
```

UPDATE:

code with modal and span containing onclick event

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)

<!-- display category and button -->
<h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
<a href="#edit-modal{{ $key }}" data-uk-modal><span onclick="editCommentModal()" class="uk-icon-plus-square"></span></a>


<!-- modal -->
<div id="edit-modal{{ $key }}" class="uk-modal edit-modal">

<h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="edit_category[]" id="edit_category" value="{{$item->category}}" />

</div>

@endforeach


function editCommentModal(){
 var inps = document.getElementsByName('edit_category[]');
 for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
    var inp=inps[i];
    console.log("edit_category["+i+"].value="+inp.value);
 }
}
```

Comment: *Obviously, this is becaue the php/html loop has a key assigned but the javascript is pulling a non-unique ID.*  So don't use a non-unique id.  Use a class

Comment: HTML Element `id` should be UNIQUE within a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)

<!-- display category and button -->
<h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
<a href="#edit-modal{{ $key }}" data-uk-modal><span onclick="editCommentModal({{ $key }})" class="uk-icon-plus-square"></span></a>


<!-- modal -->
<div id="edit-modal{{ $key }}" class="uk-modal edit-modal">

<h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="edit_category[]" id="{{ 'edit_category_' . $item->id }}" value="{{$item->category}}" />

</div>

@endforeach


function editCommentModal(id){
 var inps = document.getElementsByName('edit_category[]');
 for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
    var inp=inps[i];
    if('edit_category_' + id == inp.id)
    {
      console.log("edit_category["+i+"].value="+inp.value);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: So this works, but it lists the values for every item on the page, i just want it to vshow the values for the item selected. This function in javascript is triggered when a button is clicked

Comment: Oh that's like a whole other question. You would then have to use an onclick event, pass id of the category or id itself and show it.

Comment: I am, I have a span with an onClick that fires up this function. the onclick works but it's showing all values for the page. So I have a div with multiple items, each with their own span/button. WHen that is clicked I only want to log the data for the selected one

Comment: How would I do that though? Using your answer, it logs all the correct items. So in the context of your code, how would I do that

Comment: post your rest of related code, i would like to have a visual

Comment: You can check my update now. Basically I show the info in a list with a span icon, when that is clicked I fire up a modal containing the same info that was listed

Comment: I see your edits. So my $item doesn't have an ID in the data, but I could use $key right?

Answer (score 1):

First up; id's should be unique so I would suggest you changing id to class. To get all the values you can change the name `edit_category` to an array of input `edit_category[]`. If you want to add more hidden input fields you can use the index you're getting in the loop!

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)
   <h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
   <input type="hidden" name="edit_category[]" class="edit_category" value="{{$item->category}}" />
@endforeach

function editCommentModal(){
    var all_categories = document.getElementsByName('edit_category[]');
    var all_names = document.getElementsByName('edit_names[]');
    for (var i = 0; i <all_categories.length; i++) {
        var category=all_categories[i];
        var name=all_names[i];
        console.log("edit_category["+i+"].value="+category.value);
        console.log("edit_names["+i+"].value="+name.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I want to do this with more hidden inputs, I'd follow the same structure and it would be best for me to just do a new var/for loop for each?

Comment: @TomN. updated my answer! Do make sure that all_categories and all_names have the same length ;-)

Comment: Yes they do so that works just fine, thanks! However, this is showing the value for each item on the page, where I just want it to log the values for the selected item. So this javascript function is triggered by a click, I want to only show the values for the item clicked

Comment: Oh that's like a whole other question. You would then have to use an onclick event.

Comment: I do have an onclick event on a span tag, which fires this function. So that works, but if they click the button for a certain item, I only want to capture that data

Comment: When the span is clicked it fires up a modal which is where I'm doing these hidden inputs

Comment: Sorry if that didn't make much sense. I updated my answer with the relevent HTML. I feel like it should still work because it's using the onCLick event though

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead of an id, and then you can find them all by class and do whatever you want with them.

```
<input type="hidden" name="edit_category" class="edit_category" value="{{$item->category}}" />

document.getElementsByClassName('edit_category')
```

```js
var categories = document.getElementsByClassName('edit_category');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(categories, function(category){
  console.log(category.value);
});
```

```html
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_category" class="edit_category" value="a" />
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_category" class="edit_category" value="b" />
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_category" class="edit_category" value="c" />
```

Comment: So I'm actually trying that but the values in console.log print as undefined

Comment: getElementByClassName is going to return a NodeList (iirc), so you will have to loop over each one to access it's `.value` if you want to console.log it

Comment: OH I see. So if I add more headings and hidden inputs, then I would just establish a block like this for each